# How to create Avro Schema to have similar name for Java Avro maven generated class?

Tags: java, maven, avro

I have a use case to create Avro Schema with two string field but both the field would look similar,

1. firstName
2. first_name

These two are different field due to some legacy reason. The problem that I face now is that, on generating Java class I am getting the following exception,

```
method setFirstName(java.lang.String) is already defined in class
```

This is because the Avro maven plugin is trying to create two same setter method for each variable. For some legacy reason I can't fix it in the source end. Is there any option to handle this case in the Avro maven plugin level?

After referring to the [code](https://github.com/apache/avro/blob/master/lang/java/compiler/src/main/java/org/apache/avro/compiler/specific/SpecificCompiler.java#L1262-L1265), it looks like the code handles only when two field are exact same except the first character, but in my case this conflict strategy is not recusing me.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that what you want to do is currently possible as of Avro 1.11.0, and this is a nice feature to add to the Avro Maven plugin (at [their issues tracker](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/AVRO%5D)).

In my opinion, the generated code has never taken into account collisions caused by `snake_case` versus `camelCase` fields, but it should.